# Finding set of limit points as $ x \rightarrow 0 $

Tags: real-analysis

If the function $ f $ is defined as
$$
f(x) 
= 
\begin{cases}
|x|^{\phi - 1} \sin(1/x), & x \neq 0 \\
0, & x = 0 
\end{cases}
$$ 
where $ \phi > 0 $, how does one find the set of limit points of $ f(x) $ as $ x \rightarrow 0 $, for each $ \phi > 0 $?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HINT**

We need to consider the following cases

- $\phi>1$

$$0\le||x|^{\phi - 1} \sin(1/x)|\le |x|^{\phi - 1}\to 0$$

- $\phi=1$

$$|x|^{\phi - 1} \sin(1/x)=\sin(1/x)$$

- $0<\phi<1$

$$|x|^{\phi - 1} \sin(1/x)=\frac{\sin(1/x)}{|x|^{1-\phi}}$$

Comment: Just to confirm... in the first case, the only limit point is 0. In the second and third case, there's no limit points?

Comment: Yes the limit exists only for the first case, for the second we have limsup=$1$ and liminf=$-1$ and for the third limsup=$\infty$ and liminf=$-\infty$

Answer (score -1):

So, $\lim_{x \to 0+} x^{\phi - 1}\sin(\frac{1}{x}) = \lim_{x \to 0+} x^{\phi-2} x\sin(\frac{1}{x})$. As $x\sin(\frac{1}{x}) \to 1$ as $x \to 0$ that part has no importance, limit exists where limit $x^{\phi - 2}$ exists and has same value as that limit, and the latter limit is zero when $\phi > 2$, 1 when $\phi = 2$ and doesn't exist when $\phi < 2$